# Knowing the x axis limits in advance

Tags: matplotlib

I have data in an array `x`, I'd like to know *in advance* what x limits Matplotlib would chose for the x axis.

Is it possible? if it is possible, how?

Bonus point, does it depend on the physical length of the axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matplotlib adds the [margins](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.margins.html) to the x-range. Default these margins are 0.05 (in both directions). This does not depend on how long the axis is on the screen. Note that some functions interfere with the default behavior. For example a horizontal bar plot with only positive bars will start at `x=0` to avoid "floating in the air".

Here is some code that first "predicts" the limits and then writes out the effective limits:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as  np

x = np.random.normal(50, 10, 5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x_margin, y_margin = ax.margins()
x_delta = (x.max() - x.min()) * x_margin
print(f"Default x limits: {x.min() - x_delta:.5f}, {x.max() + x_delta:.5f} ")
ax.plot(x, np.random.rand(x.size))
fig.canvas.draw()
xlims = ax.get_xlim()
print(f"Effective x limits: {xlims[0]:.5f} {xlims[1]:.5f} ")
```

Example output:

```
Default x limits: 43.48084, 58.02320 
Effective x limits: 43.48084 58.02320
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, even if it's simpler than I'd dreamed it's exactly on spot - I've already upvoted, if there is no better answer in a couple of days I'll accept your answer as well - thanks - g

Comment: A side remark, directed not only to you but more general. When you comment under an answer, the OP is NOT notified.  This type of comment is more effective if posted under the question.